# Comparison of List in C# and vector in C++ in terms of initialization

Tags: c#, list, linq, initialization, stdvector

In C++, one can initialize a vector as

`vector<int> nums1 (100, 4);   // 100 integers with value 4`

In additions, there is something like

`vector<int> nums2 (nums1.begin() + 5, nums1.end() - 20);`

Is there something similar in C# for List?

Comment: Instead of trying to find something similar, explain what you are actually trying to accomplish and what you've tried to far to achieve it. Are you trying to generate a list with prepopulated values?

Comment: Enumerable.Repeat, ToList, Skip and Take are almost certainly what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this by [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
List<int> nums1 = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(4,100)); //100 elements each with value 4
List<int> nums2 = new List<int>(nums1.Skip(5).Take(75)); // skip first 5 and take 75 elements
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @ vivek nuna What if I want to initialize a 2-D list with a certain value?

Comment: Got `var matrix = new List<List<int>> (Enumerable.Repeat(new List<int> (Enumerable.Repeat(value, col)), row));`, though it is lit bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

First one goes this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(4, 100);
```

Second one (I´m not familiar with C++) would be this ( I suppose it means something like take elements from the fith until the 20th from the end):

```
var result2 = result.Skip(5).Take(75);
```

Be aware that both `result` and `result2` are just iterators and thus are lazily evaluated. Calling `ToList` or `ToArray` will actually materialize the collection by executing the query.

Comment: `result2` is wrong, you're trying to make a sequence of `-16` items with value `105`. What could be done is, as hinted by comment, using `Skip` and `Take`. Also maybe a comment on the fact it returns IEnumerable which are lazy compared to a C++ vector

Comment: @HimBromBeere I appreciate your approach, but probably it should be `var result = Enumerable.Repeat(4, 100);` instead. The order of the arguments is somehow reversed.